# CURL with HTTP Auth

Tags: http, authentication, curl, http-authentication

I have an URL and when I open the URL in browser, it requests for Username & password. If I don't enter username & password and just click cancel on the pop-up it shows "HTTP ERROR 401". If I enter the username & password, then the page gets loaded.

Now, I want to connect to the same URL using CURL.

I have tried the below and still getting 401 error.

```
curl -v -u username:password http://url
```

I am expecting a 200 response, but getting 401 response.

```
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Content-Length: 0
< WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
< Date: Mon, 17 Jun 2019 09:19:06 GMT
< Cneonction: close
```

Comment: Can you share the `url` that caused the problem?

Comment: @shaochuancs It's an internal URL only accessed via the LAN of the Organization where I work. Not sure If it helps If I share the url and it's not accessed on Internet